# Override animation-duration with a CSS class

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I would like to design my CSS file in this way:

```
<h1 class="bounce">Bouncing Text</h1>
<h1 class="bounce fast">Faster Bouncing Text</h1>
```

I have CSS code that looks like this, but it doesn't seem to be working:

```
.fast {
    -webkit-animation-duration: 1s !important;
    animation-duration: 1s !important;
}
.bounce {
    -webkit-animation-name: bounce-animation;
    animation-name: bounce-animation;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 2s;
    animation-duration: 2s;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}
```

The 'fast' class does not seem to actually change the animation-duration at all. The two elements bounce at the same speed.
Is there anyway to make this design work? Thanks

Comment: What about it isn't working? What is your desired result? What's happening instead?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
.fast {
    -webkit-animation-duration: 1s !important;
    animation-duration: 1s !important;
}
.bounce {
    position: relative;
    -webkit-animation: bounce-animation 5s infinite; 
    animation: bounce-animation 5s infinite;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 2s;
}
@-webkit-keyframes bounce-animation {
    from {left: 0px;}
    to {left: 200px;}
}

@keyframes bounce-animation {
    from {left: 0px;}
    to {left: 200px;}
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/x8326n81/3/

Answer (score 0):

I realized that I was applying the animation to the ::after pseudo element.  In order to see the results, I needed to adjust my fast CSS:

```
.fast,
.fast::after {
    -webkit-animation-duration: 1s !important;
    animation-duration: 1s !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`display: block;` will fix the problem. :)